# Pyjs and pyjsdl conversion

Tags: python

I was wondering how I could convert a python 2 file that uses pygame to js using pyjsdl. The file was originally in written in python 3 and then I converted it to python 2 using 3to2. But when I try to convert it, I receive a parsing error. Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Better to post here that parsing error.